# Easiest way to sort this linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a list of nodes that I would like to sort.

Node:

```
package lab.pkg14;

class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(this.data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String out = "";
        return out + data;
    }
}
```

List:

```
class LinkedList {

    private Node head;     //First item in LL
    private int length;    //Number of items.
    boolean isEmpty;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.length = 0;
        isEmpty = true;
    }

    public int getLength() {        //Getter, NO setter
        return length;
    }

    public void add(int item) {  //Adds node at the front.
        Node myNode = new Node(item);
        myNode.next = this.head;
        this.head = myNode;
        this.length++;
        isEmpty = false;

    }

    public int peek() {             //Returns value at head of list. Doesn't alter the list.
        return head.data;
    }

    public boolean find(int item) {        //Looks through the list for the int.
        boolean foundit = false;           //You'll want to use .equals() if its generic. //code
        return foundit;
    }

    public void displayList() {
        Node runner = head;
        while (runner != null) {
            runner.display();
            runner = runner.next;

        }
    }

    public int addList() {
        Node runner = head;
        int sum = 0;
        while (runner != null) {
            sum += runner.data;
            runner = runner.next;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public Node remove() {  //Removes the head.
        Node headData = head;
        if (!isEmpty) {
            this.head = head.next;
        }
        return headData;
    }

    public boolean remove(int item) {      //Removes first instance of the specified item.
        boolean foundData = false;
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = head;
        if (!isEmpty) {
            while (current.data != item) {
                if (current.next == null) {
                    foundData = false;
                } else {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;

                }

            }
            if (current == head) {
                head = head.next;
                foundData = true;
            } else {
                previous.next = current.next;
                foundData = true;
            }

        }
        return foundData;
    } //Returns true if it found it and removed it.
    public void sort() {   //Obvious, right?             

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {             //Makes debugging easier.
        String out = "";
        Node current = head;
        for (int i = 1; i <= this.length; i++) {
            out = out + current.data + " ";
            current = current.next;
        }

        return out;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Lab14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myll = new LinkedList();
        myll.add(15);
        myll.add(16);
        myll.add(17);
        myll.add(18);
        myll.add(19);
        System.out.println("Length: ");
        System.out.println(myll.getLength());
        System.out.println("Head: ");
        System.out.println(myll.peek());
        System.out.println("Full list: ");
        myll.displayList();
        System.out.println("Sum: ");
        System.out.println(myll.addList());
        System.out.println(myll.remove());
        System.out.println(myll.remove(17));
        System.out.println("Full list with 19 and 17 removed: ");
        myll.displayList();

    }

}
```

I am trying to learn how to code on my own and just can't seem to get this. I have been trying to sort these few numbers for over 3 days. I have tried other examples and all of that but I just can't get to the bottom of it. What is the easiest way to sort these numbers?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; how to write `sort`? Isn't that the whole point? To figure it out? There are all sorts of references and tutorials discussing this very subject.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: I think I have been trying insertion sort.

Comment: [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is a relatively simple sorting algorithm that is trivial to implement on a linked list.

Comment: Try writing some sort code an post back with that rather than asking SO to do it for you.

Comment: public void sort(int data) {   //Obvious, right?             
      Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;

     if (head == null)
         head = node;
     Node p = head;

     while (p.next != null)
     {
         if (p.next.data > data)
         { node.next = p.next;
           p.next = node;
           break;
         }
         p= p.next;
     }

    }

Comment: @HunterS Preferably in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

A LinkedList (either your implementation or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) keeps the items in order that they were added.  In the Java Collections LinkedList newly added items are placed at the end of the list, whereas your implementation places them at the start - but either way its the order in which they were added, rather than some order relating to the 'value' of each item which is used to maintain order.

If you want to sort the items in your list based on the value (in your case I assume the int value), you can either:

1. Maintain the desired order when adding a new item, i.e. don't just create a new node and place as the head/tail - iterate through any existing nodes in the list, comparing the value of the int to each one until you locate the correct position to maintain the desired order, and place your new node there. As your list grows, the correct order will automatically be maintained.
2. Implement the sort method you have stubbed to either re-order the entries in place (i.e. move them around within your LinkedList), or return an ordered copy of the LinkedList, keeping your existing LinkedList ordered as it is.  This will be a larger task which you could achieve using a number of different sort algorithms (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm for some ideas)

There are a few other data structures which might be better suited to this task, and would give you your sort for free e.g. TreeSet (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)